# Screen sharing or Casting on TV

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am having an app with TV streams, and I wanted to add a functionality of screen cast sharing, I had a look into this Google SDK casting, but It didnt show what I expected :
https://github.com/gianlucaparadise/flutter_cast_framework

I cloned the app and ran it to see the UI, I thought I would see a casting button to share the screen instead I saw this :

Anyone who knows how to add the screen casting for TV with flutter?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [flutter_video_cast](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_video_cast) package from pub.dev?

Comment: Thanks let me try it out

Comment: Whats your result @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris?

Answer (score 0):

I also tried but not possible in Flutter. You have to write native code, then it is possible. Android :- Android Code iOS :- iOS Code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).